# Storekit: Testing receipt validation - When to use which server address?

Tags: objective-c, storekit, receipt-validation

I am starting to get really confused about this receipt validation. So there is the live server from apple and the sandbox server for the receipt validation. When do I need to test which? Some users complain they get the message, that no receipt can be validated. So if I want to test it I get the following results:

- Xcode Simulator with sandbox server: Works
- iPhone connected to Xcode with sandbox server: Works
- iPhone connected to Xcode with live server: Doesn't work
- Testflight app connected to live server: Doesn't work

Last point I am especially confused since we wanted to make a public beta. Is this correct that the testflight app needs also the sandbox server for verification?! Or is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code?  What code?

Comment: I think nowadays you use the transaction queue and that will take care of it. If it is a really old app you'd make a connection first to the sandbox and then to the real apple server (or maybe the other way around, was long ago...)

Comment: Yeah I mean I use the transaction queue, but I want to get the expiration date of the purchase..I can only do that with the receipt right?